# System.NotSupportedException when trying to enable automatic migrations in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I get the following error message when trying to enable automatic migrations.

> enable-migrations –EnableAutomaticMigration:$true
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
> by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException:
> Could not load file or assembly 'ProdustsServerAPI, Version=1.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
> Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515) --->
> System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly
> from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be
> sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of
> the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load
> may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the
> assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.

How to fix this exeption?

Answer (score 0):

I guess It's because your project is not allowed to load any assembly from a network location. Try adding this to your app.config file, this is what that error message says.

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
       <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check the referenced versions of all Entity Framework related packages. I've seen this error, when I migrated from EF Core 3.1 to 5.0 and some packages had not been bumped yet.

Also: clean the solution (that is: delete all `bin` and `obj` folders) to make sure no outdated packages are being picked up.